# How to fix du tab alignment?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, du

I'd like to get the `du` output in neat columns.

This is what I get:

```
du -sh * | sort -hr
----
48M app
11M lib
6.7M    image.jpg
1.1M    image2.jpg
488K    code.c
488K    code.py
72K doc.txt
16K notes.txt
4.0K    README.md
```

The desired output is similar to `ls -lh` output.

Answer (score 0):

`du` outputs a <Tab> character between the size column and the name column. 
Terminals / consoles normally interpret <Tab> characters
as motion to the next character position that’s a multiple of eight. 
So you would normally get the `du` output in neat columns,
unless you have a size value that’s eight characters or more,
and that’s just about impossible with the `-h` option.

It appears that your console is configured to interpret <Tab> characters
as motion to the next character position that’s a multiple of four. 
So the (in some sense) “right” answer
is to fix your console so it handles tabs the normal way.

If you can’t figure out how to configure the tab stops in your terminal,
the other answer is to pipe the output through `expand`:

```
du -sh * | sort -hr | expand
```

Comment: Did you mean tabs strictly greater than 8? 
>unless you have a size value that’s eight characters or more...

Comment: No, when I said “eight characters or more”, I meant “eight characters or more”, ***not*** “strictly greater than eight”.  Note that `6.7M`, `1.1M`, `488K` and `4.0K` are all *four* characters (or more), while `72K` and `16K` are strictly less than four characters.